# How to use fonts with embedded colors?

Tags: wpf, fonts, colors

I want using fonts in WPF which have integral colors / decorative patterns in the symbols. But when I have tried this my text is always shown in black :
[image]

in this link ( [Color Fonts](https://www.fontspace.com/category/color) ) you u can see several fonts of the type that I am attempting to use:

[image]

How I can solve this problem?

Here is the code from the above example which uses the "ResotEDream" font from the above link:

```
<RichTextBox>
    <FlowDocument>
        <Paragraph>
            <Run Text="ABCD" FontFamily="ResotEDream" FontSize="72"/>
        </Paragraph>
    </FlowDocument>
</RichTextBox>
```

It is intended to look like the "ABCD" rendering shown above, which is a sample of that font.

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your XAML that you are setting the color of the ABCD example?

Comment: hi, ty for answer / I added XAML codes / Yea I Don't set foreground color, Because I used a color font that has its own color (see photo above)

Comment: I don't think truetypes support colors in windows.

Comment: see https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/64917/can-truetype-fonts-contain-color and https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/06/using-color-fonts-beautiful-text-icons/

Comment: I used these color-fonts in Photoshop and Microsoft Office and it worked but in Visual-Studio...

Comment: try a colored OpenType font to see if your system specifications supports it or not. such as typewithpride.com

Comment: If it works in Photoshop doesn't mean it works in WPF. these systems use different rendering techniques. And it also depends on some Windows 10 updates.

Comment: Thanks for the good links, especially the link below, It was written in the "Using color fonts in XAML" part : The XAML platform’s text elements support color fonts by default!

https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/06/06/using-color-fonts-beautiful-text-icons/

Comment: That seems to be UWP XAML, not WPF.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately you are right - I tested it in UWP and it worked but not in WPF :( What do I do now? How do I solve my problem? I mean I have to go and work with uwp?

Comment: The thing i notice about those is the fill brush is different for each character. Do you absolutely need that or could you work with something more generic? If not. There is an outside chance you might be able to use a uwp xaml island in a wpf project. How much of this will you be using?

Comment: In fact, I want to change the color of the text and the color of the vowel in Arabic texts, but because it was not possible; I went for color font, but color font is not supported in WPF (but in UWP this problem does not exist) - I mentioned it before in the following link but no one answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65314128/wpf-applypropertyvalue-not-work-for-arabic-vowel-diacritics

Comment: For different colours like in your other question you need different objects in the ui. A shape (path) of some sort per different coloured piece. Maybe there's 3 variants of an arabic font give you those pieces and you could stack 3 textblocks on top of each other with different foregrounds each. Failing that. For our game i built some ui needs letters that scale. I created a path per letter rather than using a font. Maybe you could split the pieces of each letter out yourself as paths and stack those similarly. I know zip about arabic. Can each of those letters be fixed width?

Comment: Xaml islands might be the only practical option.